# How to count total of values in the rows rather than total of rows in sql?

Tags: sql

I have a columns:

```
Product Orders   Month    
Item1        1         1
Item1        2         1
Item1        1         1
Item2        1         1
```

I want to get total of items sold every month that result would be this:

```
Product TotOrders Month
Item1           4            1
Item2           1            1
```

If i use count(Orders) as TotOrders it gives me a result of 3 for Item1. Thats the total of rows, but I want a total of values in the rows (4 for item1).

Answer (score 2):

To compute a total, you use `SUM` function on the column that you need, and a group by:

```
select Product, sum(orders) TotOrders, month
from mytable
group by Product,month
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Product, TotOrders as sum(Orders), Month 
from table group by Product, Month
```